# I am a AWS IAM user and I have created a bucket, and I want no other IAM users to access my bucket. How can I achieve it

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, restrict

I am a AWS IAM user having "S3FullPermissions". I have created a bucket, and I want no other IAM users to access my buckets. How can I achieve it. Please help me with bucket policy..

Answer (score 0):

S3 buckets and their objects are by **default private**. No one has access to them unless given explicit permissions to do so. So if you are the only one with S3 buckets permissions, no other IAM user will be able to access your buckets and objects.